# How to store all subclasses in different sets c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I want to store objects relative to their type.
I have a `Status` class which is inherited to create different status such as `Burn`, `Stun`, etc...

I would like to store statuses in sets with a set for each type (a character can a multiple burn status at once, so I want to get the set storing all the burn statuses but not other statuses).

my solutions so far looks like this

```cpp
std::map<std::type_index, std::set<Status*>> statuses;

// access all Burn statuses
for (const Burn* b : statuses.find(typeid(Burn))->second) {} // error : E0144 a value of type "Status *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const DamageModifier *"
**
```

However this is downcasting and the compiler doesn't want it to work.

My questions are as follow:

- How could I access a set and downcast it to the right type without copying
- Do you think of any other way to store all statuses of the same subtype together with easy access ?

  - I dont want to store it all in a set and dynamic cast because it starts getting expensive
  - I dont want to declare one set by hand for each new `Status` subclass.

## Edit :

The problem was that I tried to do two things at once from my last code version

- Switching from `std::set<Status*>` to `std::map<std::typeid, std::set<Status*>>` which is OK as long as you cast the result the same as before
- Trying to implicitly cast a whole set of pointer which is useless and naive, at least in this context

Both answer helped me realise the problem was that I tried to do both at once.

Comment: Why did you store them as `Status` if you need them as subclasses?

Comment: Because I don't want to declare by hand one set for each new Status. How would you declare `statuses` then? Also they are pointers. I could also declare them as `void*` but that won't fix my problems there.

Comment: You cannot use range-based for-loop like that  as assignment would require  type conversion by `dynamic_cast`. ANd whole thing smells of X/Y problem.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yeah I know my solution is probably a problem but would you have any insight on how to tacle the second question then?

Comment: I wouldn't have used set there.. yeah, I get it, you want unique objects. What prohibit them to become non-unique across borders. You probably would want a factory to generate them and not to have ownership over them on-site. For simple components like that even polymorphism might be an excessive measure.. some universal "Status" class with generalized set of parameters and visitors to process them. Look at design of games like Wow, Pathfinder, etc.. everything ECS based. they may add some buffs\debuffs ad-hoc, by introducing a new name and visitors to process data related to that name.

Comment: Downcasting is almost always a sign of a bad design. If you need `Status` and don't care which subclass is that, pass `Status`, if you need `Burn` specifically, pass `Burn`. If it turns out you need to pass 5 different containers, something is wrong with the way you designed `Status`, its subclasses or their consumers.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `Downcasting is almost always a sign of a bad design.` Are you sure? Downcasting used in CRTP for example; is using CRTP always a bad design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could I access a set and downcast it to the right type without copying

You can use `static_cast` to down cast:

```
for (const Status* s : statuses.find(typeid(Burn))->second) {
    auto b = static_cast<const Burn*>(s);
}
```

You must be very careful though to not insert pointers to wrong derived classes into wrong set. That will silently pass compilation and break at runtime (if you're lucky).

Comment: That was my initial design (I used dynamic_cast because I only had one set and needed to check the validity of the cast) so yeah I could return to that but I'm not super fan as it's quite verbose.

Comment: @startresse `it's quite verbose` I'd guess that's minuscule compared to for example definitions of those derived classes.

Comment: @startresse casting is *deliberately* verbose

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a cast *somewhere*. If you've gated insertion into `statuses` by e.g. `void add_status(Status * status) { statuses[typeof(status)].insert(status); }`, then you can safely `static_cast`, otherwise you have to be wary, as incorrectly `static_cast`ing has undefined behaviour.

If you have a lot of places where you cast collections, I'd be tempted to write some `_view_cast` templates.

```
template <typename To>
struct static_view_cast_t
{
    template <std::ranges::view View>
    auto operator()(View view) {
        return view | std::ranges::views::transform([](auto & from) -> To { static_cast<To>(from); });
    }

    template <std::ranges::view View>
    friend auto operator|(View view, static_view_cast_t c) {
        return c(view);
    }
};

template <typename To>
constexpr static_view_cast_t static_view_cast;
```

And so on for each cast you need.